# I need some area scroll-bar in table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please find the image and you can view the Jan and Dec column, I need to place a scroll bar for that two column in the sense two column space area has Jan to Dec months.

[image: January to December only scroll-bar]

This is possible for table?

Please help me!

***Above Question got very good answer.***

**another Help!**

http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/Ty29z/

please find the image and you can view the (vendor 1 quote) and (vendor 6 quote) column, I need to place a scroll bar for that two column in the sense two column space area has (vendor 1 quote)to (vendor 6 quote) vendor details[image]

Comment: okay, My question possible or not?

Comment: Honestly the only way I could think to do it was with colgroup class, but that didn't work at all so I think the answer is no. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/zAVfy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

**HTML**

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th colspan="1" rowspan="5" style="border: medium none ; width: 100px; vertical-align: top;">
            <div class="inner-table">
                <table style="text-align: left; width: 500px; border:none" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Header 1</th>
                        <th>Header 2</th>
                        <th>Header 3</th>
                        <th>Header 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-table {
    width:100px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

th {
    height:20px;
}
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/caq8F/4/

You can fiddle with the CSS to get the same style easily.

::EDIT:: Cleaned up code and updated fiddle to include some space for the scroll bar.

Comment: Please see image, (budget chart and account description)

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe this is possible. I tried by styling a colgroup but this didn't work.

[Example of tried solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/zAVfy).

The only other way I think to do it is splitting your table up into three separate tables with a wrapper div on the middle one.

[Example of split up table with div separator](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/zAVfy/1/).

Comment: Nice work, i want this work inside table because you see one more time my image. It comes colspan and the overall width 100%.