# Need a scrolling cell in an html table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have an html table that contains a cell will a lot of data (maybe 200 lines).
Rather than requiring my page to scroll, I want my cell in the table to scroll.
I understand that I need a `div` block to do this.  I defined a div block in my
css file but it is not taking.

How do I fix the height of my cell and give my data a scrollbar?

--------html table-----------

```
<table class="cmain">
  <tr>
    <td>  TOP LEFT CELL <p>
        <table> <tr> <td> A sub-table goes here </td> </tr> </table>
    </td>
    <td>  TOP RIGHT CELL <p>
       <p> A PHOTO GOES HERE.
       <p> PHOTO: {{ form.image }}
   </td>
   <td rowspan="2" valign="top" > 
       THIS IS THE CELL THAT NEEDS THE SCROLL BAR.  <div id="scrollcell">
           SCROLLER CELL <hr>
            <p> {% for customer in customer_list  %}
            <p> {{ customer }} </p>
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td> Another Sub-table goes here.
        <table> <tr> <td> A sub-table goes here </td> </tr> </table>
</td> 
   <td> A NOTES FORM FIELD GOES HERE <p>
     {{ form.notes }} </td>
 </tr>
</table> <!-- end of CMAIN table -->
```

--------css -----------

```
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid white;
}

table.cmain {
        border: 1px solid blue;
}

table.cmain td { 
        border: 1px solid blue;
    font-weight: bold;
        /*width: 300;*/
        padding: 3px; 
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#scrollcell {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a question like this a while back, take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468830/i-need-some-area-scroll-bar-in-table/7471723#7471723) and the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/caq8F/4/).

**EDIT**

Posting code here for future reference for other posters:

**HTML**

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th colspan="1" rowspan="5" style="border: medium none ; width: 100px; vertical-align: top;">
            <div class="inner-table">
                <table style="text-align: left; width: 500px; border:none" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Header 1</th>
                        <th>Header 2</th>
                        <th>Header 3</th>
                        <th>Header 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-table {
    width:100px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

th {
    height:20px;
}
```

If you wish to make the vertical and horizontal scrollbars appear just replace `overflow-x:scroll;` with `overflow:scroll` for the `.inner-table` class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to put the table into an iframe. Otherwise you can use either javascript or `overflow`.

Comment: Why is an `iframe` the easiest solution?

Comment: Easiest and worst I would like to say.

Answer (score 0):

give this td an absolute height and 100% width/height to the div

```
<td rowspan="2" valign="top" >
```

like

```
<td rowspan="2" valign="top" style="height:100px;">
```

and

```
#scrollcell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```